# Generics in Interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to implement a stack using generics.

Here are the componenets I am having,

1)Interface:

```
public interface stackInterface<T>{...}
```

2)Implementation:

```
public class Stack<T> implements stackInterface<T>{...}
```

3)Client:

```
stackInterface<Integer> s=new Stack<Integer>();
```

I just want to know whether What I am doing is the right way to do it or am I missing anything?

Comment: I would try using the built in classes. There is a Stack already, but Deque may be a better choice.

Comment: Peter, despite the existence of the usual collection classes it's still a nice way to learn about Generics and writing them. Mainly because at least a naïve collection is quite easy to write and thus doesn't distract too much from the point at hand. This doesn't seem like someone reinventing the wheel just because they need a stack and don't know there is one already.

Answer (score 4):

It looks ok-ish. Apart from the utterly wrong naming conventions, of course.

Type names in Java use CamelCase. Also interfaces are not named specially compared to classes. The usual way in Java would be to name the interface `Stack<T>` and the class `ImplementationDetailStack<T>`, cf. `List<T>` and `ArrayList<T>` or `LinkedList<T>`.

(Personally I favor the .NET convention of starting interface names with `I`, though, e.g. `IStack` for the interface and `Stack` for the default implementation.)

Comment: Your last paragraph will probably just start an endless debate so it is quite meaningless to even mention it. Most Java developers don't use the `I` prefix for a reason, it doesn't add any value.

Comment: The Java designers thought differentiating class and interface inheritance in the class declaration (`extends` vs. `implements`) is enough and I tend to disagree. Classes and interfaces are *uses* more often than created. And in *usage* being able to see at a glance whether your variable is an interface type or the actual implementation is quiet beneficial in my eyes. Also I frequently stumble in writing `List<Foo> l = new List<Foo>` just to notice, yet again, that `List` is an interface and I have to hunt down an implementation (`List` is just an example here; there are more obscure examples)

Comment: When I call a method that returns a `List<SomeClass>` that is enough for me. I don't need to know that it is an interface. Why would I?

Comment: When learning about classes versus interfaces I really liked the convention of using nouns for classes and adjectives (Cloneable, Iterable) for interfaces.

Comment: OTOH all of the Eclipse codebase respects the I... convention.

Comment: @Joey just use an IDE (like Eclipse) that can show you the difference.  Mine is set to show interface names in orange, italics.

Answer (score 2):

So far, so good, except name all types with CamelCase and don't use the word "interface" in an interface. Interface should be called `Stack` and an implementation `...Stack` where `...` describes the basic implementation principle, like in `ArrayList`.

Generally we tend to reserve the nicest and shortest names for interfaces because they appear everywhere in method signatures and variable types, whereas the concrete implementation types appear only in instantiation expressions.

Answer (score 1):

stackInterface has a problem of naming java conversion. it should be StackInterface .

[Java Naming conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)  is a good coding practice.

Interfaces: Names should be in CamelCase.

Ref:http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58

Answer (score 1):

A good idea may be to take a look at the source code for the `java.util.List` interface and its implementing classe like `java.util.ArrayList` are using generics. You can learn from there and apply to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine except the naming convention. As suggested by Dan take the took at List and ArrayList. It would be also preferable to use just interface name in interface and append Impl with interface name for the default implementation.

```
public interface Stack <T> {

}

public class StackImpl<T> implements Stack {

}

Stack<String> defaultStack=new StackImpl<String>();
```

For other implementation it is better to use List-ArrayList style convention.